# hide div unless associated number field is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of number input fields, labeled small & medium.., and a set of div's with the label small and medium. In my actually project there will be more sizes than just small and medium. When you add a number to the small number input field a text input insertsAfter the div labeled small. When you subtract a number from the small number input field, the text input field that was recently added is removed.

If the small number field is 0, I want

```
  <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Small">
```

to be hidden, if the small number field is greater than 0 I want the

```
  <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Small">
```

to show. Same goes for medium.

http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/62/
i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("input.product-quantity").val() === '0') {
        $(".name-number-field-container").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".name-number-field-container").show();
    }
});
```

and...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $input = $("input.product-quantity");
    var $field = $(".name-number-field-container");

    $field[($input.val() === "0" ? 'hide' : 'show')]();
});
```

Comment: the code you have on jsfiddle is different for the one above, which are you using ?

Comment: It seems to be working as described.  Was there a question here?

Comment: i changed the jsfiddle link. the <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Small"> to hide when number field = 0 and show when number field is greater than 0. it is hidden but does not show when I add 1